# Confused on jQuery val

Tags: jquery

I was under the impression when using val it automatically set the value of any text box named in the selector. I have several input text boxes and would like them all to be set using val:

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" size="20" class="gotowp-input-text required">
<input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" size="20" class="gotowp-input-text required">
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="20" class="gotowp-input-text required email">
```

I have two sets of these input text boxes, and I am trying to set them both with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("#firstName").val("Test");
$("#lastName").val("Test2");
$("#email").val("test@test.net");
});
```

Please see:

https://jsfiddle.net/bg1pdbw2/

jQuery will set the first selector it sees but not the second one. They have the same name. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot re-use IDs.  You've picked the same ID for the same input, which is not allowed.

Instead, consider selecting your inputs by their names:

```
$('input[name="lastName"]').val('Test2');
```

Working example:  https://jsfiddle.net/bg1pdbw2/3/

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried that but because of my php code it was conflicting with the outer parenthesis. I needed to remove the inner double parenthesis, and change the outer to double. Thank you Brad

Answer (score 0):

The basic rule for Id's to have a unique Id per page. Use class instead of Id so that it will work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601687/difference-between-id-and-class

Comment: check above link for more details

Comment: Right. I get that, but this code was being generated through php and did not want to mettle with the php. Thank you!